# absolute/relative paths for php includes

Tags: php

I have a function(orders) with many php includes in a file called extract.php

http://example.com/application/dir1/dir2/dir3/extract.php

```
function orders ($username)
{
 require ("functions.inc.php");
 define("DATAGRID_DIR", "./../datagrid/");
 define("PEAR_DIR", "./../datagrid/pear/");
 require_once (DATAGRID_DIR . 'datagrid.class.php');
 require_once (PEAR_DIR . 'PEAR.php');
 require_once (PEAR_DIR . 'DB.php');
 require_once ('./../datagrid/classes/database.class.php');

//function code here
}
```

I have another file(install.php) that calls this function inside the same directory and it works very well.

```
<?php
include ("extract.php");
orders ("643443876996");
?>
```

However, when i include it in another function in this path 
http://example.com/orders/getorder.php, it gives me error that it cannot find my files 'datagrid.class.php';

```
    <?php
    include ("include('../application/dir1/dir2/dir3/extract.php');");
    orders ("643443876996");
    ?>
```

How can I get the path referencing correct?

Comment: path needs to be absolute, not relative. Try to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and navigate from there on.

Comment: Do you mean `include ('../application/dir1/dir2/dir3/extract.php');`?

Comment: the error if from the getorder.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference from the server root, either with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] or

require_once (DATAGRID_DIR . '/application/dir1/dir2/dir3/datagrid.class.php');

etc...

Comment: ./ ../ are relative to document. / is relative to the document root.

Comment: When your function is called from a different location it is still following the same instructions for finding the include. If you describe the locations relative to the root of the site they can be found from anywhere the function is called. / starts from the site root. ./ starts from the location of the file the function is defined in.

Answer (score 1):

Relative files are always calculated from the directory where PHP binary is called.

For avoid that you can use `__FILE__` constant to refer to the actual file.

Using that you can write this:

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/my/relative/path';

include_once $path;
```

That always will produce the same path regardless where the script is called

Comment: In every single place where needed. I suggest you to store the first part realpath(dirname(__FILE__) in a constant ('MY_APP_ROOT') on your main function and use that constant in the rest of files. include_once MY_APP_ROOT . '/my/relative/path';